# Qt Error Creating SSL context on few computer

Tags: qt, ssl

In my Qt Application, I try to access to a ssh page.
On few computer I've this error :

> Error Creating SSL context()

I try all the solutions I founded :

- Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package
- Add the dlls libeay32.dll/ssleay32.dll/libssl32.dll in the path of my exe
- Add this in my .pro :

  CONFIG += openssl-linked

Nothing...
I do my test with a Microsoft 7 64bits computer

Do you have an idea ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, you have to add three dll :

- libssl32.dll
- ibeay32.dll
- ssleay32.dll

BUT take these libraries from the Qt directory (example C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\bin) not from System32...

Comment: @ take these libraries from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.1e file for 32 bit